# Sqlplus exclude results that have a string

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is there a way to query a table to exclude rows with unique ID's that have a certain string?

Example: I have a table that records user activity:
ID     Action

```
ID       activity 
jjl    Logged in
jjl    updated user contie
jjl    updated user kalka
jjl    Logged off
cdl    Logged in
cdl    updated user pilda
cdl    updated user dkcll
cdl    updated user ccffrr
```

I'm trying to exclude any ID that has a message of "Logged off" Meaning jjl wouldn't show up in my query results at all.

Comment: Typically an `ID` field is a unique identifier. So in this case, you're not really using the ID in a conventional way. Obviously Oracle lets you do it, but I'd suggest rethinking your design if this is anything more than an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID can never be null, I would go with:

```
select *
from table
where id not in (
  select id
  from table
  where activity = 'Logged off'
)
```

If it can be null, I would go with:

```
select *
from table t1
where not exists (
    select null
    from table t2
    where t2.id = t1.id
    and activity = 'Logged off'
)
```